# Is there an equivalent stats_mode from Oracle in Netezza?

Tags: sql, oracle, netezza

I need to create a view in Netezza that currently exists in Oracle. The Oracle view uses 'STATS_MODE' to return the value that occurs most often. Is there an equivalent function in Netezza?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select col1, col2 as mode
from (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by count(*) desc) seqnum
      from t
      group by col1, col2
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```